# How to keep a class hidden even if toggled, with checkboxes

Tags: jquery, html, css, checkbox

I have encountered a problem..

I'm trying to create a filtering system for a list of elements. 
Each elements has different classes. For example, each element has a class for its shape and one for its color. for example:

```
<img class="Square Red" src="Bearwithme.jpeg">
<img class="Square Blue" src="Bearwithme.jpeg">
<img class="Circle Red" src="Bearwithme.jpeg">
<img class="Circle Blue" src="Bearwithme.jpeg">
```

On the navbar, I would have checkboxes used to show-hide each element as follows:

```
 <input id="Squares" type="checkbox">
    <input id="Circles" type="checkbox">
    <input id="Red" type="checkbox">
    <input id="Blue" type="checkbox">
```

And here is the function I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Red").click(function(){
    $(".Red").toggle(this.checked);
    });
    $("#Blue").click(function(){
    $(".Blue").toggle(this.checked);
    });
    $("#Circle").click(function(){
    $(".Circle").toggle(this.checked);
    });
    $("#Square").click(function(){
    $(".Square").toggle(this.checked);
    });

});
```

Say the square checkbox and the blue checkbox are checked, how would I prevent the red circle to show up if I decided to check the red checkbox?

Here is a working example http://jsfiddle.net/JB3kM/1/

Comment: You should post a working example of what you have so far, I *nearly* understand, I think, but an example wouldn't hurt.

Comment: Ok, I added the function I have

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/0pbwaxLg/).

I would say your best course of action is to get the values of all the checkboxes, show all of the elements, and then hide the ones that do not have all of the criteria met.

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").click(function(){

    var red = $("input#Red").prop("checked");
    var blue = $("input#Blue").prop("checked");
    var sq = $("input#Squares").prop("checked");
    var cir = $("input#Circles").prop("checked");

    //Toggle all on
    $("div.red, div.square, div.blue, div.circle").show();

    //Toggle off
    if(!red)
        $("div.red").hide();
    if(!blue)
        $("div.blue").hide();
    if(!sq)
        $("div.square").hide();
    if(!cir)
        $("div.circle").hide();

});
```